# What is the percentage in code coverage calculated on?

Tags: code-coverage

Code Coverage   74% (2055/2748)

Here , what is the code coverage calculated upon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code coverage is calculated upon the number of methods called and the number of loops covered.

Try covering methods which are in some conditions like `if(a == 0) { method(){} }`
such methods are not usually covered, full fill the conditions to cover those methods.

Answer (score 1):

Code Coverage is calculated by the formula: Total Number of lines covered / (Total number of lines covered + Total number of lines uncovered)